# Routing in Angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is my first angular project and I'm using angular "ui.router" in my  application.
[This is structure of my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNW9S.png)

I have created separate route file for each module and all module inject in app.js. When I run my application my home module routing works fine but account module routing gives below error:

**"Error: Could not resolve 'login' from state ''
transitionTo................

but when I create my account module controller direct in route file it's works. I'm stuck on this

Can any one resolve this issue?

Comment: Maybe show us some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject the uiRouter module in your parent module config your states.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");

// Now set up the states
$stateProvider
.state('state1', {
  url: "/state1",
  templateUrl: "partials/state1.html"
})
.state('state1.list', {
  url: "/list",
  templateUrl: "partials/state1.list.html",
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
  }
})
.state('state2', {
  url: "/state2",
  templateUrl: "partials/state2.html"
})
.state('state2.list', {
  url: "/list",
  templateUrl: "partials/state2.list.html",
  controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.things = ["A", "Set", "Of", "Things"];
  }
});
});
```

Comment: I have already added "ui.router" in my parent module. Please see my application structure, I have created separate module wise route file. (In single page my application working fine)

Comment: If you don't show your code no one will help you with more then I did